# How to call entrySet method on Mono<Map<Entity, Integer>>

Tags: java, functional-programming, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

Let's say that I have a method **findAll** which is returning `Flux<Song>` from `ReactiveMongoRepository<Song, String>`.

Below I have traditional java stream approach to find the x top-voted songs which is suggested by @Naman:

```
return songRepository.findAll()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), this::getSumOfVotes))
    .entrySet().stream() --entrySet method is not recognized by IntelliJ
    .sorted(Map.Entry.<Song,Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
    .limit(numberOfTopSongs)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey().getId(), Map.Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> a, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Above solution works for `Iterable`, `Set` and `List` but the problem occurs when I pretend to call method `entrySet` on `Mono<Map<Song, Integer>>`. That's my first dive deep into `Web Flux` and that's why I am a little bit confused why method `entrySet` is not available for `Mono` type.

I have found a piece of code like:

```
Mono<Map<ByteBuffer, ByteBuffer>> serializedMap = Flux.fromIterable(() -> map.entrySet().iterator())
        .collectMap(entry -> rawKey(entry.getKey()), entry -> rawValue(entry.getValue()));
```

but I try to avoid repacking my:

```
songRepository.findAll()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), this::getSumOfVotes))
```

to `Flux.fromIterable` again.

I will be grateful for suggestions on what I am doing wrong or tips on how to skip this obstacle.

Answer (score 0):

It's `Map<Song, Integer>` which has `entrySet` method; if you want to apply some transformation to contents of a `Mono`, use [`map`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#map-java.util.function.Function-):

```
Mono<Map<Song, Integer>> songs = ...;
Mono<Set<Map.Entry<Song, Integer>> = songs.map(Map::entrySet);
```

Note that `map` is very common name for such a method, it's available on `Flux`, `Stream`, etc.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. This solved the problem. Taking advantage of a question, I will ask for a different one. If I want to use `.sorted(Map.Entry.<Song,Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())` as the next step in my Flux should I use `doOnNext` operator or something different?

Comment: Actually it should be a part of the operation you pass to `map` (or a separate `map`). And so should all the rest (`.sorted().limit().collect()`).

Comment: thank you for a response. Problem is that after mapping it to entrySet with `.map(Map::entrySet)` there is no available method like sort. In normal stream after `entrySet` method usage, we should recreate stream by calling `.stream` but here there is no obvious solution. Do you know how to do it on Mono?

Comment: Doesn't matter. I cannot sort a single Mono object. I used `.flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)` and now `sort()` method is available.

Comment: If you need to do more than call a single method, you can use a lambda instead of a method reference like `Map::entrySet`: `map -> map.entrySet().stream()...`